# Removing white background in gimp

Tags: color, gimp, transparency, background

I was removing white background from some pictures with color to alpha tool and all worked well. I made a quick brake and when I sat down down again to continue my work it didn't work for some reason. Now every time I use color to alpha in preview it shows me a picture without background, but when I try to export it it has a white background. Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export to a format that supports transparency (PNG, usually). When you export to JPEG a default background is added.